# Login With Linkedin Api Issue in Android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

*If Linkedin app is not installed on an android phone, my app users are getting blank screen on linkedin login. Till two days back, my users could login using Linkedin via the webview, but now they can do so only if the user has LinkedIn app.*

Answer (score 0):

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkDJV.png)

It is the picture which shows logon with LinkedIn button !When i click on Login with LinkedIn it shows me this blank white screen in web view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1U7g.png)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with their being stopped working.

LinkedIn has deprecated and stopped supporting their old mobile SDKs as per [this link](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates), so I've created a lightweight "unofficial" SDK for Android, you can use it from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/AbdAllahAbdElFattah13/LinkedIn-SDK-Android).

We also use it in our production apps, so it should be working fine. :)